# Django CMS plugin

Tags: django, django-cms

When writing a plugin the documentation states that you have to define a class that inherits from `CMSPluginBase` and you can pass info in the context. My question is what are the parameters that are passed in the `render()` function;

```
def render(self, context, instance, placeholder)
```

What is;

- instance?
- placeholder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, the [API documentation](https://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/develop/reference/api_references.html#cms.plugin_base.CMSPluginBase.render) provides a few hints. Also the docs have more detailed information on components like placeholders and custom plugins.

**`instance`**
This is the current instance of your plugin. Imagine you have created a Django CMS plugin that renders testimonials on your website. It provides fields to upload a testimonial image, a name and the quote. You could have multiple instances of this plugin on each page, so the `instance` argument holds the currently rendered data.

So, if you have five instances of one plugin (e.g. the testimonials) on a page, `render()` will get called five times independently from one another and `instance` is the reference to the currently rendered entity.

**`placeholder`**
In your templates you can define multiple placeholders, like `my_left_sidebar`, `the_footer`, `main_content`, etc. Through the `placeholder` variable you can check in which placeholder the current instance is rendered.